# Kernel core collection is not working in Centos. How do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: linux, centos, crash, kernel

I have a problem with CentOS7 not generating kernel cores after installing new kernel:

When I go through the settings right after a fresh CentOS install and trigger a kernel panic, I do get a kernel core. But after I install my own kernel, things break and I do not get a kernel core. I could not even get a core for the older kernel that came with the fresh install.

Any idea how to start troubleshooting this?

Thanks.